# Been trying to copy folders and files using shutil.tree() function in python but brings FileExistsError

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I have tried to use `shutil` module in **python**. The `shutil.copytree` fails to copy folders and brings `FileExistsError`. I have tried it using different files but it still fails.Please check

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(r"C:\Users\rapid\OneDrive\Desktop")
shutil.copytree(p/"folder_1", p/"folder_2")
```

Please check for the [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPzZA.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also post error messages as text, e.g. included in a code block, don't use images (or links to images).

Comment: I think you need to use the `dirs_exist_ok=True` keyword argument.

Comment: Thank you Timus for letting me know that. I am welcomed to this community.

Comment: Let me try that solution

Comment: Hello, `Timus` I have tried the solution, the `FileExistError` is gone but still the files aren't copied to folder_2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is probably that `folder_2` already exists on your desktop.

Comment: `Timus` your solution worked this time around. Thank you so much....... You are the best. All credit to `Timus`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code myself and works fine the first time.

After the destination folder (in your case `folder_2`) already created `shutil` can't create it again and it fails. So you can either delete the destination folder manually or using `shutil.rmtree`.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

All credit to `Timus`. He provided the solution on the comment section. Just used

`shutil.copytree(p/"folder_1", p/"folder_2", dirs_exist_ok=True)`

It works fine. Thanks ***Timux***